# Getting TypeError when installing KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy, kivymd

Getting this error when installing `KivyMD` via `pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`

```
Collecting https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
     \ 10.7 MB 639 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpdb_2q5o4
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-u9xq525y
    Complete output (42 lines):
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    running dist_info
    creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-p_dv2dq5/kivymd.dist-info'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 254, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 100, in <module>
        "tests = kivymd.tools.packaging.pyinstaller:get_pyinstaller_tests",
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 36, in run
        bdist_wheel.egg2dist(egg_info.egg_info, dist_info_dir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 408, in egg2dist
        shutil.copy(license, os.path.join(self.distinfo_dir, license_filename))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
        a = os.fspath(a)
    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpdb_2q5o4 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip install git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git@master`. It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can download whl file of KivyMD from [here](https://pypi.org/project/kivymd/#files).
[image]

Then use `pip install whlFilePath/kivymd-0.104.1-py3-none-any.whl` to install.

Fox example: `pip install E:/kivymd-0.104.1-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: `pip install E:/kivymd-0.104.1-py3-none-any.whl` It will install the stable version of `kivymd` but I need the development version (master)

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, `E:/`is the whl file path, from my link you can download whl to any place, if you download the file to `D` disk, then you need to use `pip install D:/kivymd-0.104.1-py3-none-any.whl` to install, `pip install kivymd` will  install stable  version online,but `pip install E:/kivymd-0.104.1-py3-none-any.whl` Install from a file that exists locally.

Comment: I can understand the **file storage** that you are telling, but I need the development version (master) version of kivymd not stable (`1.104.1`).

Comment: You can see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-pre
I can't understand why you need development version.